# Reaching QueuePool limit overflow in FastAPI application

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, uvicorn

I have the [following project](https://github.com/MADE-TEAM-PROJECT-1/citation_network_service) on GitHub built with FastAPI, SQLAlchemy and PostgresDB.
And during the load tests via Locust I investigated that my server fails with the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30.00
```

Here is a picture in Locust:
[image]

Why am I getting this requests as `HTTPError('500 Server Error: Internal Server Error` and not as timeout. How can I avoid this by turning this requests into timeout?

Obviously I can set `pool_size` and `max_overflow` options in engine constructor to greater values, but I don't think it's a good practice.

Is it possible to control number of session created?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am encountering the same issue now, and I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: @user7921367 Nope, rewrited my service in async way